# How can I set multiple T-SQL variables in a single SELECT query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, set

I have 3 variables: `@testid`, `@sampleid` and `@clientid`.

How can I set `@sampleid` and `@clientid` by executing this query once?

```
SELECT
  [sample].sampleid,
  [client].clientid
FROM
  dbo.[test]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[sampleslice] ON dbo.[test].samplesliceid = dbo.[sampleslice].samplesliceid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[sample] ON dbo.[sampleslice].sampleid = dbo.[sample].sampleid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[client] ON dbo.[sample].clientid = dbo.[client].clientid
WHERE
  testid = @testid
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sampleid YOUR_VAR_TYPE;
DECLARE @clientid YOUR_VAR_TYPE;

SELECT
   @sampleid = [sample].sampleid, 
   @clientid = [client].clientid
FROM dbo.[test]


-- The variables are now initialized. You can now use them below.above
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly.  I have one more coming in about a minute.  :-)  Should be the last for today.

Comment: @Mr. MacGyver: you can probably combine this with your INSERT in the other question by JOINs on this table and *notes*. The WHERE in the other question becomes the JOIn onto "test"