# populate multiple variables based on row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following variables

```
  Declare @test1 int,
            @test2 int,
            @test3 int
```

is there a way to populate the above variables based on the rows in a table? currently im doing this.

```
select @test1 = value from tables where somecode = 'test1'
select @test2 = value from tables where somecode = 'test2'
select @test3 = value from tables where somecode = 'test3'
```

Is there a better way to do this? i.e in one single select statement?

something like this is it possible?

```
SELECT @test1 = CASE code WHEN 'test1' THEN value END,
       @test2 = CASE code WHEN 'test2' THEN value END
  FROM myTable
```

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917423/how-can-i-set-multiple-t-sql-variables-in-a-single-select-query) to assign to multiple variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select
    @test1 = max(case when <testcolumn> = 'test1' then col1 else null end),
    @test2 = max(case when <testcolumn> = 'test2 ' then col2 else null end),
    ...
    from
    <your table>
    where
   test column in ('test1','test2')
```

Depending on your data, you may need to select distinct or some sort of aggregate to get it exactly right.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cce0e/17)

Comment: this wont work i don't have multiple columns i'm selecting from a SINGLE ROW.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  If you only have one row, unless your table has one column, you have multiple columns.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Raju You only have one column and only one row? So you want to assign the same value to all three variables?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion i'm bringing back rows based on different codes see answer i've updated it

Comment: Nope doesn't work leaves the first one null second variables gets assigned its value